# Can't we run a simple Angular2 code without setting-up the environment?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I just want to run below mentioned simple code without setting-up the environment, but it show error as "app.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: angular.ComponentAnnotation is not a constructor at app.js:5".

Here is my code for index.html

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>My first App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="css/main.css" />    
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.20/angular2.sfx.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <mynewTag></mynewTag>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code for app.js

```
function firstApp(){}
firstApp.annotations = [
new angular.ComponentAnnotation({

    selector: "mynewTag"
}), 
new angular.viewAnnotation({
    template: "<div><h1>Arun</h1></div>"
})
];
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
angular.bootstrap(firstApp);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why are you working on a outdated version of Angular, but have a look at the following post (https://daveceddia.com/angular-2-in-plain-js/) that uses plain JavaScript with Angular.

The syntax has changed with usage of globals like `ng.core.Component`

You can either install the node modules as shown the the post or use CDN urls such as:

https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.4.10

Comment: Do I need to install Node.js and NPM in order to run a simple Angular2 program?

Comment: No, the urls in the script section can be replaced by npm from cdn such as `<script src="https://npmcdn.com/https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.4.10"></script>` . Make sure that the versions match.

Comment: Hi, I did same but still it is not working. Can you please help? Or can you please send me the correct code to run above requirment?

Comment: Can you create a plunkr and i can look at it.

Comment: Problem solved, I'd not installed nodejs and typescript.